# Уменьшение при наведении иконок в меню

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы иконки в меню уменьшались при наведении, как  [здесь](http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_246_black_pad)?

Comment: То, что вы показали, использует Flash...

Comment: И что? Сегодня средствами js реализуется практически все возможности flash.

Comment: Это было скорее написано для @Asen

То что средствами JS можно сделать абсолютно всё что может Flash в последних браузерах я знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это очень просто делается на HTML5/CSS3:

HTML

```
<section id="test">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#test article {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
}

#test article:hover, #test article:active {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) scale(0.5);
}
```

[Пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/QQxup/)

Comment: только, по хорошему, еще-бы правила -moz, -ms, -o прописать

Comment: прописал, но в опере и ie не работает все равно

Answer (score 1):

1. Зайдите на сайт, который вы привели в пример.
2. Нажмите (В БРАУЗЕРЕ GOOGLE CHROME!) клавишу F12
3. Перейдите на вкладку "Resources"
4. Откройте в боковой панели вкладочку "Scripts"
5. Анализируйте код!

Comment: Мне хватило поклацай правой кнопкой мыши что-бы убедиться в том что это Flash)